# Python regex findall between square brackets

Tags: python, regex

I have the following body of text and I want to extract all data in between the square brackets e.g. for the given text

```
a = '\tvar mydata = [{\nZWeight:"13.00",\nStyleName:"FIRECREEK SOLID",\nColorName:"TRADITION"\n}\n]'
```

I want to extract

```
{\nZWeight:"13.00",\nStyleName:"FIRECREEK SOLID",\nColorName:"TRADITION"\n}
```

I have tried

```
re.findall(r'var mydata = \[(.*?)\]',a)
```

but it came up as an empty list. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

The `\n` newlines in your source string are the likely problem.  In non dot all mode, `.*` cannot traverse over newlines.  Try running your regex find all in dot all mode:

```py
a = '\tvar mydata = [{\nZWeight:"13.00",\nStyleName:"FIRECREEK SOLID",\nColorName:"TRADITION"\n}\n]'
output = re.findall(r'var mydata = \[(.*?)\]', a, flags=re.S)
print(output)

# ['{\nZWeight:"13.00",\nStyleName:"FIRECREEK SOLID",\nColorName:"TRADITION"\n}\n']
```